# Storing an interpolated string as a string variable for use as a messagebox message

Tags: c#

Currently I am displaying a Message Box in multiple locations as follows ...

```
MessageBox.Show($"{CommandHandlerMessage} \n\n" + $"Source process = {sourceProcess}", $"{messageBoxTitlebar}", MessageBoxButton.OK, messageBoxImage);
```

Is there a way to assign the message component to a string like ...

```
string messageBoxMessage = "{CommandHandlerMessage} \n\n"" + $""Source process = {sourceProcess}"", $""{messageBoxTitlebar}"", MessageBoxButton.OK, messageBoxImage"
```

so that I only need to show the string as follows (or something like it) ....

```
MessageBox.Show($"{messageBoxMessage}");
```

I've tried escape sequences on the quotes but I can't get it to work.

---

In case anyone should find this helpful I successfully implemented Akash KC's suggested code as ...

```
        Func<string, string, string, MessageBoxButton, MessageBoxImage, MessageBoxResult>
        messageBoxFunc = (commandHandlerMessage, sourceProcess, messageBoxTitle, messageBoxButton, messageBoxImage) => MessageBox.Show($"{commandHandlerMessage} \n\n Source process =  {sourceProcess}",
                         $"{messageBoxTitle}",
                         messageBoxButton,
                         messageBoxImage);

        messageBoxFunc(commandHandlerMessage, sourceProcess, messageBoxTitlebar, messageBoxButton, messageBoxImage);
```

Comment: I don't think string interpolation works that way, it is a compiler feature not a run-time thing, the compiler is looking for a variable named `messageBoxMessage`. Also you don't need to concatenate strings if you are using `\n`, you can just do `$"{CommandHandlerMessage} \n\nSource process = {sourceProcess}"`.

Comment: String interpolation is a compiler trick--it turns your string into the equivalent `string.Format` call. You might look at the [SmartFormat](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat.NET/wiki) library.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the advice on concatenation using \n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `string interpolation`, you can not achieve your requirement as string interpolation returns string as this interpolation will be converted to `String.Format` method which returns `string` as return type.

If your purpose is to reuse, you can simply create a delegate which will display message box as per your requirement.

```
Func<string, string, string, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon, DialogResult> messageBoxFunc = 
                (handlerMessage, sourceProcess, messageBoxTitle, button, icon) =>
                MessageBox.Show($"{handlerMessage} \n\n\"Source process = {sourceProcess}\"",
                                $"{messageBoxTitle}", 
                                button,
                                icon);

//Calling above delegate
messageBoxFunc("HanldlerTest1", 
                "sourceprocessTest1", 
                "Title1",
                 MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                  MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

As you stated in the comment that you need to use across multiple forms, you can create static delegate in your utility class and call it statically.

You can follow given code approach :

**Util.cs**

```
internal static class Util
    {
        internal static Func<string, string, string, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon, DialogResult> MyMessageBoxFunc =
                (handlerMessage, sourceProcess, messageBoxTitle, button, icon) =>
                MessageBox.Show($"{handlerMessage} \n\n\"Source process = {sourceProcess}\"",
                                $"{messageBoxTitle}",
                                button,
                                icon);
    }
```

Now, you can use above static delegate in your forms :

```
 Util.MyMessageBoxFunc("HanldlerTest1",
                "sourceprocessTest1",
                "Title1",
                 MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                  MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful suggestion.

I want to execute messageBoxFunc in multiple command handlers in multiple classes.

Where is the best location to declare Func and the messageBoxFunc without getting the CS0236 error?  At the moment its in each command handler like a local variable.  This works but I have multiple copies of Func.

Comment: Updated answer as per your comment

Comment: Thanks AKC - most appreciated.